# How do you embed a certain element from a webpage with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I was wondering how to embed a certain element from a webpage using jQuery or something other JS related. For example, I am creating a Chrome extension that has a portable COMM popup for Ingress. I found the id for the div (it's "comm", pretty straightforward.) and I did the jQuery code:

```
var chat = $('#comm')
```

and I got the HTML code back. I need to get that element in my popup.html with  or something of the sorts. Many thanks!

EDIT: Here is the code I have now. (Just the body but I have jQuery referenced in the head)

```
<body>
    <p><h2>Links:</h2></p>
    <p><h3><a href="http://decodeingress.me/">DeCode Ingress</a></h2></p>
    <div class="portablemap"><embed src="http://ingress.com/intel"><script src="chat.js"></script></embed></div>
    <div class="chatter"></div>
</body>
```

Chat.js:

```
$(".chatter").append($('html').find('#comm'));
```

Comment: `.clone` it you mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, one thing that might be causing problems is that the `embed` tag is supposed to be empty, so you shouldn't have the script tag inside it.  Not sure if that is the problem, just an observation.

Also, I've never seen an `embed` tag used for embedding HTML.  Again, not sure if that matters, but you normally would embed HTML using an `iframe`.

If the browser interprets the embed as an iframe when the mime-type is text/html, then perhaps you're running into a same-origin policy issue.

Comment: Tried using an `iframe` but still no luck. Is there any way I can extract the elements inside of the `body` tags from the `<html>` in the iframe?

Comment: Same-origin policy... forgot about it... I just used the `--disable-web-security` command line option and it worked. I'll just edit the Chromium source for whoever uses it.

Answer (score 1):

How about:

`$("#YourElementId").append($('#comm'));`

Using JQuery, can't you just append the element?

Expanding on the comment by @Omar, you could also append a clone of that element if you want it duplicated instead of relocated:

`$("#YourElementId").append($('#comm').clone());`

Comment: The thing is, is that it's _inside_ of the `<embed>` element. jQuery returns `[]` when I do `$('#comm')` or `$('#comm').append('#chat')` where chat is the id my div. How can I make it so that jQuery can see inside of the embedded HTML?